# Access to an element in PivotItem - WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Here is my MainPage.xaml :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot Title="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">

        <!--Pivot record-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="record">
            <StackPanel>
                 <Button Click="Record" Name="RecordButton" Width="260" Height="260">
                      <Image Name="SaveImage" Source="Assets/Pictures/save.png" Width="140" />
                 </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

I'm not able to access **RecordButton** or **SaveImage** from MainPage.xaml.cs... How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to access?

Comment: for example changing the image source using c# `SaveImage.Source = ...;`  SaveImage is not recognised as an object...

Comment: Fixed! I just restart visual studio...